# How to float a nav(div) to the right within a wrapper?

Tags: html, css

Hi guys I'm pretty much having a difficulty on how to do this properly... I could probably do it with an absolute position and just placing it to a certain point or even just with setting a margin to make it approximatively at the position I want it to be. I just want to make it the RIGHT way and not have it get messed up if I increase/decrease the length of the menu

Here is what I got so far :X

http://jsfiddle.net/W4ydD/
Thank you

TLDR: I want A B C D to be floating to the right of #wrapper only and not to the right of the page :X

```
[      [THELOGO             A B C D]     ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/W4ydD/2/

You need to move your `nav` inside the wrapper then float it to the right.

Comment: Oh my god no wonder I had so much trouble I thought it WAS within #wrapper already -.- thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS float:right on your ABCD.

```
header nav
{
    color: rgb(255,128,0);
    float:right;
}
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/W4ydD/1](http://jsfiddle.net/W4ydD/1/)

Comment: That makes it float to the right of the page and not to the right of #wrapper